# What's the best way to move space-delimited tokens from one attribute to another in XSLT-2.0?

Tags: attributes, token, xslt-2.0, tokenize

I'm trying to move space-delimited tokens from one attribute to another in XSLT-2.0. For example, given

```
<!-- SOURCE DOCUMENT -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <p class="foo"/>
    <p class="foo bar baz"/>
    <p class="foo bar baz" outputclass="BAR"/>
    <p class="foo bar baz" outputclass="BAR HELLO"/>
</root>
```

I need to move @class="foo" to @outputclass="FOO" and @class="bar" to @outputclass="BAR", deleting the source attribute if it becomes empty and augmenting the target attribute if it exists (simple token-set operations):

```
<!-- RESULTING DOCUMENT -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <p             outputclass="FOO"/>
    <p class="baz" outputclass="FOO BAR"/>
    <p class="baz" outputclass="FOO BAR"/>
    <p class="baz" outputclass="FOO BAR HELLO"/>
</root>
```

I think I have everything figured out except the actual token-moving part. Every direction I go down ends up complicated and broken, and I feel like XSLT-2.0 surely has a simple approach that I'm missing.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mine="mine:local"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <!-- baseline identity transform -->
    <!-- (for non-elements - attributes, whitespace PCDATA, etc.)  -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|(node() except *)">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- for element nodes, remap attributes then copy element -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <!-- get original attribute sequence -->
        <xsl:variable name="atts1" select="@*"/>

        <!-- use our function to remap two attribute tokens -->
        <xsl:variable name="atts2" select="mine:remap($atts1, 'class', 'foo', 'outputclass', 'FOO')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="atts3" select="mine:remap($atts2, 'class', 'bar', 'outputclass', 'BAR')"/>

        <!-- stuff updated attribute sequence into element -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:sequence select="$atts3"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- remap  @from_att~="$from_token"  to  @to_att~="$to_token" -->
    <xsl:function name="mine:remap">
        <xsl:param name="orig_atts"/>
        <xsl:param name="from_att"/>
        <xsl:param name="from_token"/>
        <xsl:param name="to_att"/>
        <xsl:param name="to_token"/>

        <!-- ******** TOKEN-MOVING MAGIC!?! ******** -->

        <xsl:sequence select="$orig_atts"/>
    </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Basically I need to figure out how `TOKEN-MOVING MAGIC!?!` can move a single token (including deletion of empty "from" attributes). I've searched quite a bit but I haven't seen this particular problem covered.

Edit: The number and names of attributes to remap can be anything, and their values are case-sensitive. It's the magic inside the `mine:remap` function to remap a single value in an attribute sequence that I'm looking for.

Edit: The reason for approaching attribute modification with a function is that we have a number of different token remappings to apply to different files, and I hoped to allow our non-XSLT-savvy users to easily adjust the remappings to their needs. I was unable to figure out how to provide similar generalization with a template-matching-based approach.

Thanks!

Comment: See a short, pure XSLT 2.0 solution below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a short XSLT 2.0 solution** (just 26 lines):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="p/@class[tokenize(., ' ') = ('foo', 'bar')]">
    <xsl:if test="tokenize(., ' ')[not(. = ('foo', 'bar'))]">
        <xsl:attribute name="class" 
             select="string-join(tokenize(., ' ')[not(. = ('foo', 'bar'))], ' ')"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:attribute name="outputclass" select=
      "upper-case(string-join(
                   (
                    tokenize(., ' ')[. = ('foo', 'bar')],
                    tokenize(../@outputclass, ' ')
                                 [not(lower-case(.) = tokenize(current(), ' '))]
                    ),
                    ' '
                              )
                  )"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="p/@outputclass[../@class[tokenize(., ' ') = ('foo', 'bar')]]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <p class="foo"/>
    <p class="foo bar baz"/>
    <p class="foo bar baz" outputclass="BAR"/>
    <p class="foo bar baz" outputclass="BAR HELLO"/>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<root>
    <p outputclass="FOO"/>
    <p class="baz" outputclass="FOO BAR"/>
    <p class="baz" outputclass="FOO BAR"/>
    <p class="baz" outputclass="FOO BAR HELLO"/>
</root>
```

**Update**:

Here is the same transformation with almost everything parameterized, as requested in a comment by the OP, just 32 lines:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:param name="pfromName" select="'class'"/>
 <xsl:param name="ptoName" select="'outputclass'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pTokens" select="'foo', 'bar'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pnewNames" select="'FOO', 'BAR'"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p/@*[name() = $pfromName][tokenize(., ' ') = $pTokens]">
    <xsl:if test="tokenize(., ' ')[not(. = $pTokens)]">
        <xsl:attribute name="{$pfromName}"
             select="string-join(tokenize(., ' ')[not(. = $pTokens)], ' ')"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:attribute name="{$ptoName}" select=
      "upper-case(string-join(
                   (
                    tokenize(., ' ')[. = $pTokens],
                    tokenize(../@*[name()=$ptoName], ' ')
                                 [not(lower-case(.) = tokenize(current(), ' '))]
                    ),
                    ' '
                              )
                  )"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template 
    match="p/@*[name()=$ptoName][../@*[name()=$pfromName][tokenize(., ' ') = $pTokens]]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Update2**:

Here is a completely parameterized XSLT 2.0 transformation (not using the `upper-case()` and `lower-case()` functions), just 37 lines:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:param name="pfromName" select="'class'"/>
 <xsl:param name="ptoName" select="'outputclass'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pTokens" select="'foo', 'bar'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pnewNames" select="'FOO', 'BAR'"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p/@*[name() = $pfromName][tokenize(., ' ') = $pTokens]">
    <xsl:if test="tokenize(., ' ')[not(. = $pTokens)]">
        <xsl:attribute name="{$pfromName}"
             select="string-join(tokenize(., ' ')[not(. = $pTokens)], ' ')"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:attribute name="{$ptoName}" select=
      "string-join(
                   distinct-values(
                            (for $token in tokenize(., ' ')[. = $pTokens],
                                    $n in 1 to count($pTokens),
                                    $ind in $n[$token eq $pTokens[$n]]
                                  return $pnewNames[$ind]
                             ,
                              tokenize(../@*[name()=$ptoName], ' ')
                              )
                                    ),
                    ' '
                    )
                  "/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template
  match="p/@*[name()=$ptoName][../@*[name()=$pfromName][tokenize(., ' ') = $pTokens]]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following sample I have tried to delegate as much as possible to templates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:param name="tokens" as="xs:string*"
    select="'foo', 'bar'"/>
    
  <xsl:param name="collation" as="xs:string">http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/collation/html-ascii-case-insensitive</xsl:param>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[@class][exists($tokens[contains-token(current()/@class, ., $collation)])]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:variable name="new-att" as="attribute()">
              <xsl:attribute name="outputclass"/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, $new-att[not(current()/@outputclass)]">
              <xsl:with-param name="tokens-found" 
                select="$tokens[contains-token(current()/@class, ., $collation)]"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="@class">
      <xsl:param name="tokens-found"/>
      <xsl:variable name="remaining-tokens" select="tokenize(., ' ')[not(. = $tokens-found)]"/>
      <xsl:if test="exists($remaining-tokens)">
          <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="$remaining-tokens"/>
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="@outputclass">
      <xsl:param name="tokens-found"/>
      <xsl:variable name="new-tokens" select="$tokens-found[not(contains-token(current(), ., $collation))]"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="$new-tokens, ."/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzkTcx/1

I haven't implemented the upper-case transformation of the tokens to be moved, I guess it should be easy to add that.

The code uses XSLT 3 with XPath 3 and the function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-contains-token but it has a definition in the spec that you could use in a user-defined XSLT 2 function. It is of course also easy to not declare the identity transformation using `xsl:mode` but by spelling it out.

XSLT 3 is available with Saxon 9.8 or later for Java and .NET, with Saxon-C for C/C++, with bindings for PHP and Python and with Saxon-JS 2 inside of modern web browsers and for Node.js.

Comment: Thank you for your post! I updated my post to clarify that the number of attributes, and their names and values, could be anything. It's the parameterized magic inside the function to adjust a sequence of attributes that I need. However, I'm learning quite a bit by going through your code in the xsltfiddle you provided!

Comment: @chrispitude, which XSLT 2 processor do you use? Since 2017 vendors like Saxonica have updated their implementations to XSLT 3 (i.e. Saxon 9.8 and later are XSLT 3 processors) and in XSLT 3 you can even parameterize `match` attributes using a shadow attribute `_match` and static parameters e.g. `<xsl:param name="source-attribute-name" static="yes" as="xs:string" select="'class'"/>` and `<xsl:template _match="@{$source-attribute-name}">...</xsl:template>`.

Comment: I'm using Saxon inside the latest version of Oxygen XML Editor, so XSLT 3 is absolutely an option.

Comment: I added another note explaining why I attempted to use a function (although this might or might not be the best way). I think I could figure out how to match a *particular* attribute via templates and perform the remap, but I am stumped how I'd do this for an arbitrary number of remappings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with for the `mine:remap()` function:

```
<!-- remap  @from_att~="$from_token"  to  @to_att~="$to_token" -->
<xsl:function name="mine:remap">
    <xsl:param name="orig_atts" as="attribute()*"/>
    <xsl:param name="from_att"/>
    <xsl:param name="from_token"/>
    <xsl:param name="to_att"/>
    <xsl:param name="to_token"/>

    <!-- get tokenized list of values of "from" attributes -->
    <xsl:variable name="from_att_values" select="tokenize($orig_atts[name() = $from_att], ' ')"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- does the "from" attribute contain our value to replace? -->
        <xsl:when test="$from_att_values = $from_token">

            <!-- if so, iterate through attributes to preserve their order -->
            <xsl:for-each select="$orig_atts">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <!-- if "from" and "to" attributes are the same, replace $from_token with $to_token in-place -->
                    <xsl:when test="(name(.) = $from_att) and ($from_att = $to_att)">
                        <xsl:attribute name="{name(.)}" select="for $t in $from_att_values
                            return ($t[$t != $from_token], $to_token[$t = $from_token])"/>                        
                    </xsl:when>
                    <!-- if "from" attribute, define with $from_token value removed -->
                    <xsl:when test="name(.) = $from_att">
                        <xsl:variable name="new_from_att_values" select="$from_att_values[not(. = $from_token)]"/>
                        <xsl:if test="count($new_from_att_values) > 0">
                            <xsl:attribute name="{$from_att}" select="$new_from_att_values"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <!-- if "to" attribute, define with $to_token value added -->
                    <xsl:when test="name(.) = $to_att">
                        <xsl:attribute name="{$to_att}" select="distinct-values((tokenize(., ' '), $to_token))"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <!-- if there was no "from" attribute to modify above, create it here -->
            <xsl:if test="not($orig_atts[name() = $to_att])">
                <xsl:attribute name="{$to_att}" select="$to_token"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>

        <!-- if not, return original attributes -->
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:sequence select="$orig_atts"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>
```

I iterate through the attributes to preserve their order, then I use xsl:choose to handle the from (remove a token), to (add a token), or other (copy) attributes.